# Reading and grouping char values from a source file

Tags: char

I have stumbled upon a problem when creating a program of mine.

I have produced a text file called "values.dat", and within this file I have simply added characters such as below:

```
Z
D
H
V
Q
Z
D
H
.... and so on for example. I am using C# Language with visual studio 2010. regards.
```

I know how to read them into my program, but I do not know the how to GROUP these char values together such as that there will be "AAA" and "BBB" and "CCC" etc instead of having the above set of data in my example.

Could anyone help in actually grouping these char files?

Comment: Which technology are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using C# you can try using GroupBy:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("values.dat");
var groups = ((IEnumerable<char>)text)
    .GroupBy(c => c)
    .Select(g => string.Concat(g.ToArray()));
```

To print it to the console:

```
foreach (string group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(group);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately with that, nothing is shown in the console.. even though i have shown the path the the values.dat file...? any ideas?

Comment: I am using C# language, with visual studio 2010

Comment: @cameron: Your question has been reformatted so that the characters are one per line instead of all on one line. So perhaps use ReadAllLines instead.